# Add Sitecore Form Fields with Javascript

Tags: sitecore-forms, javascript

Is it possible to add a sitecore form field to a form with javascript and if so, how should I approach it?

Comment: Hi Nick - could you give more details about your requirement? Do you mean from an admin screen within the CMS? Editing from the delivered site? How is the user going to add a field?

Comment: Once I create the form, I would like to attach some javascript code so that when the user clicks a button on the form another sitecore form input field is added to the form. @RichardSeal

Comment: To clarify further, I mean once I create the webpage and add the form to it

Comment: Is it mandatory for the input fields to be in two different forms?

Comment: @adarsh it is the same form but I just want to dynamically add form elements on the click of a button

Comment: You could use the Hidden form field(avilable with Sitecore Form Extensions) to store the HTML and then onClick event read the value of the hidden field and insert into required placeholder

Comment: Thanks @AbhayDhar

Comment: Which Sitecore version are you using? Sitecore has added conditional fields that might already help you: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/use-conditional-logic-for-your-forms.html